# How to parsing XML using JQuery with this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

This is my XML.

```
<algorithms class="list">
  <AbacusDataSample id="28" timestamp="2021-04-08 03:30:13.188 UTC">
    <data>
      <datum key=".PW_1m_NWS" value="C"/>
      <datum key="ceilAlg.ceilometer_sensor_status" value="OK"/>
    </data>
  </AbacusDataSample>
<algorithms>
```

I would like to show only value from key=".PW_1m_NWS" so that's mean "C". But my code show all value from "datum". This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('data.xml', function(data) {
            var datatabel = "";
            $(data).find('algorithms datum').each(function() {
                var $output = $(this);
                var oke = $output.attr('key');
                datatabel += "<tr><td>" + oke + "</td></tr>";
            });
            document.getElementById("TabelData").innerHTML = datatabel;
        });
    });
```

What's the solution of my problem? Please anyone help me. ty

Comment: Any chance you could paste the XML in text instead of a screen capture since you have the script in text anyway?

Comment: i've done. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

i've added condition `if ($output.attr('key') == ".PW_1m_NWS")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('data.xml', function(data) {
        var datatabel = "";
        $(data).find('algorithms datum').each(function() {
            var $output = $(this);
            var oke = $output.attr('value');
            if ($output.attr('key') == ".PW_1m_NWS") {
              datatabel += "<tr><td>" + oke + "</td></tr>";
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("TabelData").innerHTML = datatabel;
    });
});
```

Comment: now it should show all values of `datum` where `key=".PW_1m_NWS"` this correct?